# Powershell template

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm working on a signature creator script for the company where I work.
It checks for the logged in user and gets the data from a `CSV` file.

The problem is that I need different templates. One has a mobile number, other one needs a logos, no mobile number, no logos no mobile number etc.

So I have created 4 `HTML` templates that do what I want them to do, the only thing now is that when something changes you need to change it in *all the templates*.

Is it possible to create only one template and fill it with modules or something?

So you have one HTML template and add mobile or logos table into it if the user has it in the CSV file.

**Here is the code, i stripped the html areas:**

```
$css = @"
.signature, .signature td {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans serif;font-size:12px;color:#808080;}
.signature hr {background-color:transparent;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;}
.signature .disclaimer {font-size:11px;}
.signature A {color:#3a7ae2;}
.signature A:hover {text-decoration:none;color:#305fab;}
.signature A img {border:none;}
.signature .seperator {padding-top: 10px;padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 10px;margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 0px;}
.signature p {margin-bottom:0.5em;margin-top:0;}

.signature td {padding-top: 10px;padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 10px;}
.signature td:first-child {padding-left: 0;}

.signature .nowrap, 
.signature span, 
.signature A {white-space:nowrap;}
.signature .MsoNormal {margin-top:0;margin-bottom: 1em;}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .signature tr {display:block;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 0;}
    .signature td {display:block;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;}
    .signature .seperator {display:none;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;}
    .signature [style*="white-space:nowrap;"] {display:block;}
}
"@
$template = @"
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<style type='text/css'>
{0}
</style>

{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}
"@
$template_mobile = @"
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<style type='text/css'>
{0}
</style>

{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}
"@
$template_logo = @"
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<style type='text/css'>
{0}
</style>

{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}
"@
$template_logo_mobile = @"
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<style type='text/css'>
{0}
</style>
{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}
"@

# File settings
$filename = [Environment]::UserName
$folder_path = "C:\Users\$filename\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Handtekeningen"

# CSV file location and get row where username is logged in user.
$content = Import-CSV -Path "\\shares.e-wise.it\Install\handtekening\Uitrolscript\export.csv"
$user = $content | where username -eq $Env:USERNAME

# Is user is not in CSV or double stop and close
if (!$user -or $user.Count -gt 1) {
  Write-Host 'No user, or multiple users found'
  Write-Host "Closing in 3 seconds."
  Start-Sleep -s 3
  exit
}

# Get all info from CSV file
$name= $user.'realname'
$title= $user.'jobtitle'
$phone= $user.'phone'
$mobile= $user.'mobile'
$email= $user.'email'
$company= $user.'company'
$hnummer= $user.'hnummer'
$afdeling= $user.'afdeling'

# Check if map "Handtekeningen" exist else force create it.
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\Users\$filename\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Handtekeningen | Out-Null

if ($mobile -like $null -And $afdeling -notlike "Education") {$template -f $css,$name,$title,$phone,$email,$company,$hnummer | Out-File -Force $folder_path\$filename.htm}
elseif ($mobile -notlike $null -And $afdeling -notlike "Education") {$template_mobile -f $css,$name,$title,$phone,$mobile,$email,$company,$hnummer | Out-File -Force $folder_path\$filename.htm}
elseif ($mobile -like $null -And $afdeling -like "Education") {$template_logo -f $css,$name,$title,$phone,$email,$company,$hnummer,$afdeling | Out-File -Force $folder_path\$filename.htm}
elseif ($mobile -notlike $null -And $afdeling -like "Education") {$template_logo_mobile -f $css,$name,$title,$phone,$mobile,$email,$company,$hnummer,$afdeling | Out-File -Force $folder_path\$filename.htm}
else {Write-Host "Nothing to do fix in export.csv"}

# Set file to Readonly (problem is it cannot be overwriten)
Set-ItemProperty $folder_path\$filename.htm -name IsReadOnly -value $true

# Saving and sleep for 3 seconds
Write-Host "Saving signature."
Write-Host "Closing in 3 seconds."
Start-Sleep -s 3
```

**The CSV build up is:**

`username,realname,jobtitle,phone,mobile,email,company,hnummer,afdeling`

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question. If and when the link dies this question will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is one template containing *two format strings* (`{0}` for the `css` and `{1}` for the body):

```
$template = @"
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<style type='text/css'>
{0}
</style>

{1}
"@
```

Now you pass two parameters to the format string. The first is the css, the second is a list of body content which you combine using `-join`. Example:

```
if ($mobile -like $null -And $afdeling -notlike "Education") {
    $template -f $css, ($name,$title,$phone,$email,$company,$hnummer -join ' ') | Out-File -Force $folder_path\$filename.htm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple template like so:

```
"testing {0} {2}" -f 1, 2
```

The problem is when the template gets bigger and there are many variables it can get confusing getting the variables in the correct order. A better solution would be to have named variables in your template.

If you use a function like so:

```
function Invoke-Template
{
    param([string]$template, [hashtable]$data)
    [regex]::Matches($x, '\{\{\w+\}\}').Groups | % {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            name = [regex]::Match($_.value, '\w').Value
            regex = [regex]::Escape($_)
        }
    } | % {$template = $template -replace $_.regex, $data[$_.name]}
    return $template
}
```

You can then create a template with named placeholders in a {{}} format

```
$x =  @"
Test {{name1}}
Test {{name2}}
Test {{name1}}
"@
```

Next create a data hash using the same named palceholders

```
$data = @{name1 = '1'; name2 = '2'}
```

Then invoke the template:

```
Invoke-Template -template $x -data $data
```

you can easily modify the data and invoke the template again with different data.

```
$data['name1'] = 33
Invoke-Template -template $x -data $data
```